How can I remove/unprotect a password-protected .xlsb file in Excel?
I have an Excel .xlsb file that is password protected. Unfortunately, I have forgotten the password and I need to access the data in the file.
I have tried a few methods, such as using VBA code to remove the password protection, but none of them have worked.
Here is the VBA code I have tried:
Here is the VBA code I have tried:
Sub PasswordBreaker()
    'Breaks worksheet password protection.
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer
    Dim i4 As Integer, i5 As Integer, i6 As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 65 To 66: For j = 65 To 66: For k = 65 To 66
    For l = 65 To 66: For m = 65 To 66: For i1 = 65 To 66
    For i2 = 65 To 66: For i3 = 65 To 66: For i4 = 65 To 66
    For i5 = 65 To 66: For i6 = 65 To 66: For n = 32 To 126
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Chr(i) & Chr(j) & Chr(k) & _
        Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & _
        Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
        MsgBox "One usable password is " & Chr(i) & Chr(j) & _
            Chr(k) & Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & _
            Chr(i3) & Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
         Exit Sub
    End If
    Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
    Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
End Sub

I expected this code to remove the password protection, but it did not.
I have also tried using online tools, but they have not been successful either.
I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to remove the password protection from this .xlsb file.

Is it a open file password, sheet protect password or workbook protect password?

open file password

The code in OP is for sheet protect password. For open file password, brute force attack might be the only option. I guess you need to use a commercial software.
